# jquery & ajax uploading images twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery script that uploads images via ajax and I noticed that for some reason, it's uploading images twice. Once during the ajax step and then they are embedded as hidden values in the form, then when somebody clicks submit the form, the upload process starts again, when it should really not because the images are already on the server. I see it because I use Chrome and it shows 'Uploading (19%)..' etc on the bottom left corner again when I click submit. This isn't my script and I'm really bad at jQuery so I can't figure out what's wrong. Is there anything obvious here that would make it upload again on submit?

```
function media_sync(form_name, media_type, file_path, file_url, file_embed, nb_uploads, max_uploads, upload_id) {
   var radio_buttons = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < form_name.length; i++) {
      if (form_name.elements[i].type == 'radio' && form_name.elements[i].checked == true) {
         radio_buttons[form_name.elements[i].name] = form_name.elements[i].value;
      }
   }

   var jsHttp = new JsHttpRequest();
   var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

   if (jsHttp == null) {
      alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
      return;
   }

   var media_name = '';
   switch (media_type) {
      case 1:
         media_name = 'ad_image';
         break;
      case 2:
         media_name = 'ad_video';
         break;
      case 3:
         media_name = 'ad_dd';
         break;
   }

   var media_box_name = 'display_media_boxes_' + media_name;

   file_embed = base64Encode(file_embed);
   var url = relative_path + 'file_upload.php';
   var action = url + '?do=add&media_type=' + media_type + '&file_url=' + file_url +
           '&file_embed=' + file_embed + '&nb_uploads=' + nb_uploads + '&upload_id=' + upload_id;

   var thumbnail_div = document.getElementById('display_media_boxes_' + media_name);
   var new_content = document.createElement('div');

   if (file_embed != '') {
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            var response = xmlHttp.responseText;

            var results = response.split('|');

            if (results[5] != '') {
               alert(results[5]);
            }
            else {
               new_content.innerHTML = results[3];

               while (new_content.firstChild) {
                  thumbnail_div.appendChild(new_content.firstChild);
               }

               var hidden_div = document.getElementById('hidden_media_boxes');
               var hidden_content = document.createElement('div');
               hidden_content.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="' + results[1] + '[]" id="hidden_' + results[2] + '" value="' + results[4] + '">';

               while (hidden_content.firstChild) {
                  hidden_div.appendChild(hidden_content.firstChild);
               }
               nb_uploads++;
            }

            document.getElementById('item_file_url_' + media_type).value = '';
            document.getElementById('item_file_embed_' + media_type).value = '';

            if (nb_uploads >= max_uploads) {
               document.getElementById('btn_upload_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_upload_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_url_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_embed_' + media_type).disabled = true;
            }
            document.getElementById('nb_uploads_' + media_type).value = nb_uploads;
         }
      };
      xmlHttp.open("POST", action, true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
   else {
      jQuery.blockUI({ 
          message: $('#uploading_image'), 
          css: { 
              top:  '20%', 
              left: ($(window).width() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
              width: '400px'
          } 
      });


      var image_loading = document.createElement('div');
      image_loading.innerHTML = '';
      thumbnail_div.appendChild(image_loading);

      jsHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (jsHttp.readyState == 4) {
            var response = jsHttp.responseText;

            var results = response.split('|');

            if (results[5] != '') {
               alert(results[5]);
               thumbnail_div.removeChild(image_loading);
               setTimeout(jQuery.unblockUI, 500);
            }
            else {
               new_content.innerHTML = results[3];

               while (new_content.firstChild) {
                  thumbnail_div.replaceChild(new_content.firstChild, image_loading);
               }
               setTimeout(jQuery.unblockUI, 500);

               var hidden_div = document.getElementById('hidden_media_boxes');
               var hidden_content = document.createElement('div');
               hidden_content.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="' + results[1] + '[]" id="hidden_' + results[2] + '" value="' + results[4] + '">';

               while (hidden_content.firstChild) {
                  hidden_div.appendChild(hidden_content.firstChild);
               }
               nb_uploads++;
            }

            document.getElementById('item_file_url_' + media_type).value = '';
            document.getElementById('item_file_embed_' + media_type).value = '';

            if (nb_uploads >= max_uploads) {
               document.getElementById('btn_upload_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_upload_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_url_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_embed_' + media_type).disabled = true;
            }
            document.getElementById('nb_uploads_' + media_type).value = nb_uploads;

            for (var i = 0; i < form_name.length; i++) {
               if (form_name.elements[i].type == 'radio' && radio_buttons[form_name.elements[i].name] == form_name.elements[i].value) {
                  form_name.elements[i].checked = true;
               }
            }
         }
      };

      jsHttp.open("POST", action, true);
      jsHttp.send({file: file_path});
   }
   jQuery('#upload_form').attr('target', '_self');
}
```

The HTML form is pretty basic, with a bunch of hidden value fields that are just variables and the image upload section, like this:

```
<form id="upload_form" action="new.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ad_create_form">

<input class="upload_button" type="file" name="item_file_upload_1" id="item_file_upload_1"
         onchange="media_sync(ad_create_form, 1, 
         this.form.item_file_upload_1, 
         document.getElementById('item_file_url_1').value, 
         document.getElementById('item_file_embed_1').value, 
         document.getElementById('nb_uploads_1').value, 
         5, 
         '000000015');"  />

<input name="finish" id="finish" value="Add" type="submit" class="btn">

</form>
```

Thank you so much if anybody can spot what's causing this! :)

Comment: My initial guess is that it has something to do with the form submit itself.  Can you post the html with the form and whatever is triggering this function?

Comment: Will do, just a sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an "onchange" which triggers the media_sync function which then runs the Ajax to post the data.  Then you also have the form itself submitting the data.  This is why it is uploading twice, once for the Ajax and once for the form submit.  You need to pick one rather than using both.  I'm not sure which one you want to go with as it depends on exactly how you want the page to work.  My guess is that the Ajax is sufficient so remove the form submit (since the only thing in the form is the one input anyways).

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I'll look into this right now. The way it works is that the ajax uploads the file and also creates the hidden fields, so I'll try and find a work-around that.

Comment: You can do it that way, but then you need to either remove or deactivate the submit for the form, unless there is something else you are trying to submit.  Or, you could put the hidden input outside of the form so it doesn't get passed up in the submit.

Comment: Yeah, it allows people to add the title and description of the image and when it's uploaded it creates the hidden fields so that it knows which images they are and then they can submit it. It's all in 1 form :\

Comment: What if I changed the "onchange" part to "onclick"? It would then only run when somebody clicks the button to upload the image but not when the form is submitted, right?

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it helped me track down the problem. Now onto fixing it :) Thank you.

Comment: See if you can put some sort of identifier in the hidden field rather than the full file info.  That way you can identify the file without having the file itself resubmit.  Depending on your db structure, returning the id from the table could work.